# Is there library available to access .env file PHP and Node JS for configuration?

Tags: php, node.js, configuration, web-config, environment-variables

I have project where need to read config details from .env file using NodeJS and PHP. Is there any way to do this or any libraries available to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own little functions to do the trick, or you can simply use existing implementations like [for node](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) and [for PHP](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: Please do not write your own in a worth way than the existing one... Also you can look at symfony/dotenv for the PHP version, slightly different to Vlucas, especially as you can't override existing env variables: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html